# Engine stops and re-starts by itself

Tags: toyota, sequoia

---

After braking car at a stop light, or any where else, it "faints", does not die, since it re-starts by itself after a few seconds. But until it re-starts, it does not respond when stepping on the gas. Please help!

Comment: You may want to expand on your question:

-Does this happen always or only when the engine is cold/warm?
-What does the car drive like after "fainting"?
-Diesel or gasoline? EFI or carburettor?

Just a few off the top of my head.

Comment: What year is your toyota?

Comment: The Sequoia is 2004. Never had any mechanical problem prior to this. It happens no matter if the car is cold or hot (I'm in Florida, so it is never really cold). The car rides perfectly after the "episodes", as if nothing happened. It runs on gas.